# Name of the song in the trailer of "A Lull in the Sea"

Tags: music, nagi-no-asukara

In the [official trailer of *A Lull in the Sea* by NIS America](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rukiDx9hYDM), there is a song playing in the entire trailer.

What is the title of the song?

Answer (score 2):

The song is *凪-nagi-* by Ray. It's the 3rd track in the album *ebb and flow*.

It's streamable on the [Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/track/4w5dun5ufA2bO6RUio9mUv)

[The lyrics](https://yumehokori.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/nagi-no-asukara-ray-nagi-lyrics/).